# Unable to manage work space for git source control in VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, git, source-control-explorer

I'm working on a project which is connected to the git source control plugin. When i set source control to none, the solution keeps asking me the root directory when it is on running mode. However when i try to manage work space for git source control, no option for source control is visible in file menu and even disabled from View/other windows. 
I need to commit all the changes made in the past, and that's what i've done but also want to remove source control for git from the project to be able to run the project smoothly.
I hope i have written things that is understandable.

Comment: Is it a .gitignore issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35496478/6309?

Comment: I've tried deleting .gitignore file from the project, yet didn't change anything

Comment: And with a more complete .gitignore? Or, just for testing, with a .tfsignore?

Comment: I usually get the dialogue box of "The source file for project is different from where the module was built". Search for this thing too, but didn't get any help either.

Comment: There is no .tfsignore linked to the project.

Comment: Yes, I meant creating one just for testing

Comment: Well sorry, i dont have any idea about this. I haven't worked on source control before. Regarding this project which uses git source control plugin creating mess.